# How to Disable/Restrict selection of year in DateTimepicker

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I am using datetimepicker to select only day and month, Year is irrelevant.

How do I disable/restrict the year selection by user.

or rather year shouldn't be shown when user tries to select the date

Comment: I don't think Year can be really irrelevant, what should you do with leap year then?

Comment: Hmmm....Good point, Had not thought about leap year :-) .

Answer (score 2):

If you restrict the two dates that the user can choose between on the `DateTimePicker` as well as set a custom format for the picker itself, you can effectively have an all in one Up/Down control that selects date time. If year is not important, you can set the `MinDate` and `MaxDate` values to a leap year to get a full range. This of course means that you'll need to extract the Month/Day out in the back end code and process it how you wish.

Here are the options, all available from the designer.

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = new DateTime(2012, 01,01);
dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = new DateTime(2012,12,31);
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! Yes this would work, but I wanted regular dropdown(which is more intuitive) than Updown selector.