# XAML DatePicker without a year?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm totally new to XAML & WPF and I'm trying to edit an existing program. The job is to add a field to select the date. But it's not a date on particular year, rather a date for a yearly recurring event, such as birthday.

I found the [DatePicker on microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker?view=netframework-4.8), but I'm not sure if I can set it up to do what I want. Leap years and other weirdness are not a concern at this moment.

Comment: I would suggest using a combobox or a textbox.

Comment: @Cid Yeah sorry. As I said, I'm new to this. So new I forgot what it's called properly.

Comment: @AndréSanson That would require me to write all the validation of existing dates that the date picker already has.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica no worries, xaml is just some xml format that contains your form

Comment: There is no validation involved, january is always 31 days and so on, but for 
 february you can have a max of 29 days since you don't care about leap years.

Comment: I think you can simply hide the year in a `DatePicker`, and set it to a leap year, so you are sure all dates are within a valid range. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613318/how-to-disable-restrict-selection-of-year-in-datetimepicker) but I don't know how to *translate* it into xaml

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTimeUpDown](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DateTimeUpDown) control from WpfToolkit. Install NuGet package [Extended.Wpf.Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/) and use DateTimeUpDown with format "MonthDay"

```
<extToolkit:DateTimeUpDown Format="MonthDay" Value="{Binding SelectedDate}" />
```

[image]

Comment: That's not very user-friendly